# double closures to detect swipe direction

Tags: javascript

The following doesn't reset my closure x and y variable to zero on each swipe. Would you be so kind to advice me how to reset my x and y variable to zero on each swipe? Also feel free to use better implementation techniek like currying or something to make it more functional. Note that I am more interested in why this doesn't work and closure / currying implementation techniques then detecting the swipe direction itself.

```js
    ;(function(){
      const t = function(start){
        let x = 0
        let y = 0
        let x1 = 0
        let y1 = 0
        if (start) {
          return function(evt){
            x = 0
            y = 0
            console.log(x, y)
          }
        } else {
          return function(evt){
            const touches = evt.changedTouches
            if (x1 > touches[0].clientX) x++
            if (y1 > touches[0].clientY) y++        
            x1 = touches[0].clientX
            y1 = touches[0].clientY
            console.log(x, y)
          }
        }
      }
      document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", t(true)) 
      document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", t(false))     
    }())
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
open mobile mode and swipe in different directions
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: x and y should be reset to 0 between swipes, but it just keep on incrementing instead.

Comment: `x`, `y` should each be set to `0` at `touchstart` handler, yes?

Comment: yes and in the log you can see it does get triggered, but the second closure doesn't take it into account for some reason i don't understand.

Comment: At chromium `DevTools` device emulation downward swipe does log incremented numerical values at `console`

Comment: `t(true)` knows nothing about `t(false)`. They are completely different closures on completely different stack frames. Are you expecting them to affect each other?

Comment: yes but don't know how to do it

Comment: Why do you expect `0` to be logged? The condition passed to `t` returned the function set at `if (start)`. You can call the function `N` times then adjust global variable or remove event handler and attach a new event handler. Or call the function once, reattach event handler.

Comment: It's not possible.. I think you misunderstand how closures work. You are not getting a live link to the variables in the enclosing scope, you are essentially getting a snapshot of them at execution time and keeping them around in a stack frame. `t(true)` has a snapshot of `x, y, x1, y1` and `t(false)` has a completely different snapshot of those same variable names. And any future modifications only affect that closure's respective variables

Comment: Ok that counts as the explanation why, thanks. Feel free to answer so i can accept and maybe a work around solution how to do it properly.

Comment: @GertCuykens Bergi posted a nice solution, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `t` creates its own scope with its own `x` and `y` variables. This is exactly what you don't want, so drop that closure. Create both handler functions in the same scope:

```
;(function() {
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    let x1 = 0;
    let y1 = 0;
    document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", (evt) => {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        console.log(x, y);
    });
    document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", (evt) => {
        const touches = evt.changedTouches;
        if (x1 > touches[0].clientX) x++;
        if (y1 > touches[0].clientY) y++;      
        x1 = touches[0].clientX;
        y1 = touches[0].clientY;
        console.log(x, y);
    });
}());
```